# What math formulas are used here for this to be equal?

Tags: calculus, summation

I don't understand how the yellow markings are equal. The start and end index is flipped and minus has gone from the exponent somehow. **What happens here?**
[image]

Comment: It's called _reindexing_.

Comment: Think of it as index substitution. Let $k=-n$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=-1} (\dots)= \sum_{-k=-\infty}^{-k=-1} (\dots)=\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty}(\dots)$

Comment: Isn't the very last expression different from the two in yellow?

Comment: @coffeemath, it is. Its a screenshot before one more term was added to it. You should add 1 to it and it will be equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, a technique known as [reindexing](http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-1/sigma-notation/changing-summation-limits/) was used, as mentioned by Parcly Taxel and dxiv in the comments.

The original sum was as follows:

$$-\sum_{n = -\infty}^{-1} z^{-n}$$

Let $k = -n$. Introducing this transformation alters the sum as follows:

$$-\sum_{-k = -\infty}^{k = -(-1)} z^{k} = -\sum_{k = \infty}^{k = 1} z^{k} = -\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} z^{k} = -\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} z^{n}$$

We can also validate this transformation by writing out some values as follows:

$$-\sum_{n = -\infty}^{-1} z^{-n} = -\sum_{n = -1}^{-\infty} z^{-n} = - (z^{-(-1)} + z^{-(-2)} + z^{-(-3)} + \cdots) = - (z^1 + z^2 + z^3 + \cdots) = -\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} z^{n}$$

I hope that helps!